# Java - Spring Boot: Unable to create a qr when deployed on heroku

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku, classpath

I'm working on a spring boot application in which I have to generate some QR codes using Zxing library in one of the folders of my resources and creating a zip file and further deleting those QR code .png images. I'm able to do it in localhost, however, when I deployed the application on Heroku it is unable to locate the path
Below is my code:

```
private void createQrCode(String data, String fileName) {
        String charset = "UTF-8"; // or "ISO-8859-1"
        Map hintMap = new HashMap();
        hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);

        try {

            BitMatrix matrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(new String(data.getBytes(charset), charset),
                    BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 400, 400, hintMap);
            File file = new File("./src/main/resources/qr/"+fileName+".png");
            MatrixToImageWriter.writeToFile(matrix, "png", file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
```

I understand that I have given path in wrong way becuase when it will be packaged as jar, resources will be moved to a path which cannot be accessed like this. I'm looking for the solution for the same. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

It is different from the asked question as in all the question people asked about reading a resource however in this question I'm asking about writing a resource that too using Zxing library which might be a issue here.

Comment: Are you deploying with Git?

Comment: Yes, I'm deploying it with git.

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path starting with `/app`?

Comment: Could you please give more info on this, this might save my life.

Comment: Use a path like `/app/src/main`. It won’t work locally but you’ll know if it works at all on Heroku that way

Comment: Let me try, probably I can test it by running the JAR only at localhost.

Comment: By app do you mean my java project name or the name of the app on heroku?

Comment: I mean literally “/app” because that’s the directory on Heroku you code runs in

Comment: Thanks a ton @codefinger you are a life saver, is there any way such that my code will work for both localhost and on heroku?